# Ошибка при заполнении таблицы SQLite данными из CSV файла

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, csv

```
import sqlite3
import csv

connection = sqlite3.connect('DBname.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
table = cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    Patronymic TEXT,
    Birth_Date TEXT,
    login TEXT,
    snls TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    phone TEXT
    )""")
connection.commit()

with open('CSVname.csv', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    csv.field_size_limit(10**8)
    for line in csv.reader(file, delimiter=' '):

        try:
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, Patronymic, Birth_Date, login, snls, email, phone) VALUES('{line[4]}','{line[5]}','{line[6]}','{line[7]}','{line[26]}','{line[40]}','{line[57]}','{line[58]}')")
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            connection.commit()
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\DB\convert.py", line 25, in <module>
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, Patronymic, Birth_Date, login, snls, email, phone) VALUES('{line[4]}','{line[5]}','{line[6]}','{line[7]}','{line[26]}','{line[40]}','{line[57]}','{line[58]}')")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

В моей CSV таблице 62 столбца, в каждом из них содержаться данные.

UPD:
Пример line

```
['4762046\tgv02052007@yandex.ru\t\\N\t\\N\tВладимир\tСергеевич\tГерасимов\t2007-05-02\t9263500749\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t2017-06-15', '23:31:12.939266\t2021-08-29', '01:23:53.830237\t\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t1\t0\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\tgerasimovvs-9\t2179138\t11ce10b5-699f-4737-bbf1-e9ed3d44e312_nsi3\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\tf\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t{}\tf\t\\N\t183-662-944', '05\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\tf\tf\tf\tf\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t36212074\t\\N\tgv02052007@yandex.ru\t79263500749\t919300\t11ce10b5-699f-4737-bbf1-e9ed3d44e312\t\\N']
```

Comment: Поймайте это исключение, да напечатайте line и посмотрите - что там, сколько там полей. Может это вообще пустая строка из одного пробела

Comment: @CrazyElf line = 

['4762046\tgv02052007@yandex.ru\t\\N\t\\N\tВладимир\tСергеевич\tГерасимов\t2007-05-02\t9263500749\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t2017-06-15', '23:31:12.939266\t2021-08-29', '01:23:53.830237\t\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t1\t0\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\tgerasimovvs-9\t2179138\t11ce10b5-699f-4737-bbf1-e9ed3d44e312_nsi3\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\tf\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t{}\tf\t\\N\t183-662-944', '05\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\tf\tf\tf\tf\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t\\N\t36212074\t\\N\tgv02052007@yandex.ru\t79263500749\t919300\t11ce10b5-699f-4737-bbf1-e9ed3d44e312\t\\N']

Comment: В этом списке три элемента, типа строка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в разделителе.

Если открывать CSV файл в редакторе то он разделён пробелами, а если посмотреть в переменную line то там появляются `\t` в качестве разделителя.

Что бы все работало корректно достаточно при открытие файла указать `delimiter='\t'`

Comment: Ну вот - сами во всём разобрались. Достаточно было сделать отладочную печать - и всё стало понятно.